# tweak intensity of blur effect inside UIVisualEffectView in Swift

Tags: swift, gaussian, blurry, uiblureffect, uivisualeffectview

I'm using this code to create a blur effect inside my view:

```
let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
blur.frame = CGRectMake(180, 10, 200, 750)
myView.addSubview(blur)
```

is there any way to tweak the gaussian function producing the blur in order to achieve different level of "out of focus" effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no other parameter in `UIBlurEffect` , I think the only way is to use the CIFilter preset `CIGaussianBlur` to blur the background View and use its key `inputRadius` to adjust the level.
If you want to achieve the same effect as so called `light`/`dark`/`ExtraLight`, you can compose this filter with other filters.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the actual `UIBlurEffect` cannot change, but there is a workaround.

Changing the `alpha` component of the `UIVisualEffectView`, will give a subtle blur effect.

```
let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
blur.frame = CGRectMake(180, 10, 200, 750)
blur.alpha = 0.4
myView.addSubview(blur)
```

**Swift 3**

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.alpha = 0.4
blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Comment: Apple advises to not use the alpha value.
an alpha value < 1 will make the actual (sharp) background visible and lays the blur ontop of it